# Interpreting a problem in relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, special-relativity

Problem statement : The event $E$ has coordinates $x=5, ct = 3$ in the $S$ system. What must the velocity of the observer $S$ be, so that event $E$ happens simultaneously with event $O$ taking place at the origin?

I worked this out with Lorentz transformation and found an answer ; $\frac{-4}{3}c$. I have two issues. First, the lack of a stationary observer. Comparing the POV of a stationary observer and a moving observer seems ( so far ) to be what relativity is all about. The second one is my question. So, the relevant effect here is time dilation right? But to me, the effect only manifests itself when there is a stationary observer and a moving observer. Moving clocks run slow, and this can lead to situations, where the events are simultaneous to a stationary observer, but not to a moving observer.

Comment: The velocity of observer S relative to what? I simply don't understand the question. [I think the term 'observer' leads to all sorts of confusions. Frames of Reference are what matter in Special Relativity. Rant over.]

Comment: Your problem statement is incomplete. You have specified the position of E in the frame of S, so in that frame E is not simultaneous with an event at the origin in that frame. I think what you mean is that O is at the origin of some other frame moving relative to S- is that the case?

Comment: No, this is literally everything that has been given. I agree it is very confusing, and hoped someone with more experience in relativity would be able to open it up for me.

Comment: @Variations  Your time might be better spent tackling well-posed questions.

Comment: I think it's a fair textbook question. The usual assumption is that the origin event where two inertial-observers/inertial-astronauts meet and their tx-planes are coplanar with their relative velocity.  The analogous geometry problem is: find the slope of the line (through the origin) that is perpendicular to a line joining the given point and the origin,

Comment: A velocity of (-4/3)c for an observer is unphysical. We expect $|v|<c$.  Rather than trying to use a formula, try drawing a position-vs-time graph ( a spacetime diagram ) [possibly with PHY-101 or relativity axis-conventions].  [Hint: in Euclidean geometry, the product of the slopes of a line and its perpendicular is equal to -1. In Minkowski spacetime geometry, that product is equal to 1.]